# Does apache 2.4 have a hard limit on connections somewhere?

Tags: php5, apache-2.4

Im using Apache 2.4 with prefork.

My MPM directives are set as follows:

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
MinSpareServers 200
MaxSpareServers 400
StartServers 200
ServerLimit 1300
MaxClients 1300
MaxRequestWorkers   1300
MaxRequestsPerChild 10000
</IfModule>
```

However my server-status page shows:

```
Parent Server Config. Generation: 1
Parent Server MPM Generation: 0
Server uptime: 34 minutes 54 seconds
Total accesses: 551221 - Total Traffic: 11.8 GB
CPU Usage: u8151.55 s2320.18 cu.02 cs.11 - 500% CPU load
263 requests/sec - 5.8 MB/second - 22.5 kB/request
1024 requests currently being processed, 0 idle workers

WKWKKWWWWKWKKKWKKCRWWKWWKKWKKWKWKWKWWWWWKKKWKWWKKWKKWWWWWKWWKWWK
WWWWKWKWWWWWKWKKWKWKWCKWKKKKKWKKWWKKCKKKKWWWKKWKKWWWKKWCKKWKKKKW
WWKKWKKWWWKWKWWKKKWKKWWWKKWWKKKWWKKKKWKKWKCKKWKKWKKKKWWWKWKKWKWW
WWKWWKWWKKWKWKKWKRWKWKKWWWWWWKCKKKKKWWWKWWWKKKKWWKWWKWWKKKKWWKKK
WKKKWWWWWWWKWKWKWWKKWKKKKKKWKWWKWWWKKKKWKKKWWKKWWKKWKWKWWWWKKWKW
KWKWWWWKCWKKKCWKKWWWWWKWKWWKWKWRWKKWWKWKWKKWWKKWKWKWKKKKWWKKKWKW
WKKKKKWKKKKWWKWKWKWWWKKKWWKWCCKWKWWKKWKKWWCKKWWWWKKWKWWWWWWWWKKK
WWKKKWKWKKKKKKKKWKKKKKKKWWWCKWWWKKWWWWKWCWWKKKKWKWWKKKWKWKWWWWWW
WKWKKKWKWKKWWWWKWWWWWKKCWKWWKWKWWWWWWKWWWWKKWWWKWWWWKWKWKKKWKKWK
WWKKKWKWWWKKWWWKWKWKWKKKKWKWWWWWWWKKWWWWKKKCKKKWKWKWWWWKWKWWWWWW
WWKKKWKWWWKWWKWWKKWKWKWKWKKWKKWKKKCKKWWWKWCWKKWWKKWWKKWKKWWKKWWK
WWKKWKWKKWKWKWKWWKWKKWWKKWWKKKWKWWKKWWWKKWWKKCKKKWWKKWKWWWCWKKWK
KKWKWKWWWWWKKKKKKKWKWKWKWWWWKKKWWKWKWKKKWKWWWKWCWWKWKWWKKKWWWCWK
WCWCKWWKKWKWWKWKKWWWKKWWKRKWWKKWWWKWKWWKWKKWWWKKWWKWKWKWWWKWKWKW
WKWKWWKWKKKWWWKWWWKCWWWWKWWWKKKKKKWKWKKKKKKKKWKKWWWWWWWWWKWWWKKW
KWKKKWWKKWWKWKWWKKWWKKKKKWKWWWKKWKWWKWWWKKKWKWCKKKKWWKWWKWCKKCKK
SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS.......................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
....................
```

Notice the line that says 1024 requests currently being processeed with 0 idle workers.  It just pegs at 1024 requests.

Now at the top of my **/etc/init.d/httpd** I have **ulimit -HSn 32768** so I don't think it's an open files limit issue.

I can't really think of why connections are getting cut at 1024 even though my MaxClients is set higher and server-status seems to want more connections but stops at 1024.

Comment: Is there anything in the error logs?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Apache 2.4 ServerLimit docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#serverlimit):

> There is a hard limit of ServerLimit 20000 compiled into the server
>   (for the prefork MPM 200000).

So, you should not be hitting the hard limit.

I've had trouble adjusting `ServerLimit` in earlier versions; try `apache2ctl stop` and then `apache2ctl start`. (Using graceful and even restart failed to pick up the change.)

On a side note: You may want to reduce your `KeepAliveTimeout` and/or `MaxKeepAliveRequests`, or try `KeepAlive Off` since you have so many workers in the 'K' state. Also, those 'S'es indicate that the server is having trouble starting up workers, likely due to the 500% CPU load (which I assume is the max available.) If tweaking the KeepAlive settings doesn't help, you may need to look into upgrading the server or load balancing.

Answer (score -2):

You should investigate HA Proxy (if you have not already) to split up your requests to multiple servers.

Even on fast hardware, you are pumping alot of data from a single machine. If you need to keep a single machine, try Nginx. It will run circles around Apache at high load.

Comment: You have completely failed to address the question that was asked.

Comment: I was attempting to guide the user that if there is this much traffic to one server, it might be time to look at load balancing.